# div shifting between position:fixed and position:absolute during scrolling

Tags: javascript, css, html, scroll, positioning

I am looking for a way to imitate the behaviour of the menu to the left on this website:
http://www.nectarboutique.com/collections/on-sale

Meaning: I need a div that has to be absolutely positioned (CSS styled) somewhere close to the top of the page, until the user scrolls down beyond a certain point, and then it changes to `position: fixed`. Then, when it reaches somewhere near the bottom (before it intersects with the footer), it has to change back to `position: absolute`.

This would be a big help to me, if anyone knows a solution?

Comment: nectarboutique link is broken

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are using a custom jQuery code. See a good tutorial on how to do this here:
http://css-tricks.com/scrollfollow-sidebar/

Or you could download a jQuery plugin to help you on your way:
http://plugins.jquery.com/node/8152